# storing struct in array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm fairly new to C++, and I've run into an issue with storing structs in an array. I've searched around the boards on this already, but no one seems to have my specific problem.

I'm creating a text-based RPG game which requires a dynamic array of spells. The spells are structs, defined like so:-

```
struct spell
{
    std::string mSpellName;
    int mRequiredMagicPoints;
};
```

I then create and initialise two instances of the struct:-

```
spell fireBall {"Fire Ball", 10};
spell magicMissile {"Magic Missile", 5};
```

Then, in main(), I try to store these two instances in a vector array:-

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<spell> mSpells[2];

    mSpells[0] = fireBall;
    mSpells[1] = magicMissile;
}
```

However, Xcode shouts at me and reads "no viable overloaded '='"

I have also tried to store these structs in a traditional dynamic array, but it still won't compile. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. Don't use wrong tags.

Comment: Maybe you meant `std::vector<spell> mSpells(2);` , a vector of 2 elements. What you actually wrote is an array of 2 empty vectors

Comment: [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/)

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector<spell> mSpells[2];` Defines an array of vectors. It seems you only want a vector of two elements. So you start but just defining a vector:

```
std::vector<spell> mSpells;
```

Then you have [several options](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for adding elements to it:

```
mSpells.push_back(fireBall);
mSpells.emplace_back("Magic Missile", 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared an array of two `vector`s of `spell`s. You clearly want just one `vector`, so you want to say the following:

```
vector<spell> mSpells(2);
```

This will also initialize `mSpells` to have two default-constructed elements.

You might also want to write:

```
vector<spell> mSpells;
mSpells.reserve(2); // optional, good idea
mSpells.push_back(fireBall);
mSpells.push_back(magicMissile);
```